# Taylor expansion of smooth function with compact support

Tags: taylor-expansion, distribution-theory

If one has a function $\varphi(x) \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, it is not analytic (except for in the trivial case $\varphi(x)=0$), so in the Taylor expansion $\varphi(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\varphi^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!} +R_n(x)$ the remainder doesn't go to zero as $n$ increases. 
Can one say more about the Taylor expansion? Does it hold that $R_n(x) \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? Forgive me if the question is stupid - one still has that $\bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\varphi^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!} +R_n(x) \bigg)  \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The remainder must be smooth as it is the difference of two smooth functions.

Comment: Right, thanks! But one cannot say anything about it's support?

Comment: You can, since a non trivial polynomial does not have compact support, then $R_n$  cannot. That is, outside of the support of $\phi$ you must have that $R_n$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! You don't possibly have a reference of a proof of this?

Comment: See my previous comment. Outside of the compact support, you have $R_n(x) = - \sum \text{polynomial stuff}$, so it is non zero everywhere except for a finite number of points.

Comment: Sorry, a proof of what?

Comment: Great, got it, thanks again!